# Function to map an object throws "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, assign

I have this function below on TypeScript and I cannot compile due to the following error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Even searching on Stack Overflow, I don't really understand why yet.

```
const function = (list: IListType | undefined) =>{
   let listpush: AType[]=[]
    list?.item.map(
        it =>
        {(it.values && it.values?.key && it.values?.value)?
            listpush.push({
                attr1: it.name,
                attr2: it.values.key,
                attr3: it.values.value,
            }):null
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a new javascript feature called [Optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) which is only supported since `typescript 3.7`. Make sure you have at least `version 3.7` or newer in your react project.

Keep in mind that `map` is meant to transform an array, you have to return a value for each item in the callback. I changed it to `forEach` in the example below:

```js
const myFunction = (list: IListType | undefined) =>{
    let listpush: AType[]=[];

    list?.item.forEach(it => {
        if(it.values && it.values?.key && it.values?.value){
            listpush.push({
                attr1: it.name,
                attr2: it.values.key,
                attr3: it.values.value,
            })
        }
    })

    return listpush;
}
```

and alternative would be to use `filter` and `map`:

```js
const myFunction = (list: IListType | undefined): AType[] => {
    if(!list){
        return [];
    }

    return list.item.filter(it => {
        return it.values && it.values?.key && it.values?.value;
    }).map(item => ({
        attr1: it.name,
        attr2: it.values.key,
        attr3: it.values.value,
    }))
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer! I'm using typescript 3.7+ so I adopter your first amazing solution :) . Just a question, on this part "if(it.values && it.values?.key && it.values?.value){}" why typescript do not accept it with the "?" constructor in the place of the "if" like "(it.values && it.values?.key && it.values?.value)?{} ". Thanks again!

Comment: The error seems to be caused by the usage of `map` without returning a value in the closure. This may be a linting rule from eslint because your typescript is valid:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBlgGcwBUCeADigN7CQC2AXMiSHBRDTlKAOYA0yAbnADYBXCFhokA1hHzMwrEJx78h02WwC+qgNoBdVQFgAUKEixEKAIIFiJVcgMGEAexA5kFfADEBIBGGBPkALzIABR82GA0GOGWKAA+yF4AJhAwoBCJAJSBAHwkBsgFfBBgyGE4hAJYABY0FkQQ2gHaANz5BW2F4QD8AHTkEBQ9FHCEwR0FE+Q54xO0weQ9vILCyABkq8gLS0JYvRL4axtbisK92xAZXTOzE2VgFdU9D1XBefo3HzdwYDIAjDQLeiMDjXT4Tb4yABMALAixOWB6+xB7zBnwhUAAzDC4csEedkaiJqoMlQQAI+HxQcg9CiChkDKogA

Answer (score 1):

Mistake 1: no return value

Mistake 2: 'function' is a keyword and cannot be used as an identifier

Misconception: use Array.map() instead of forEach and a buffer variable

Misconception: make the function parameter nullable instead of expecting "undefined" (which does the same)

Refactoring advice: use filter to remove elements you dont want to map

```
const mapperFunction = (list?: IListType): AType[] =>
    list?.item.filter(it => it.values && it.values?.key && it.values.value)
              .map(it => ({ attr1: it.name, attr2: it.values.key, attr3: it.values.value }))
```